# Java-Numbers aren't adding/subtracting in my addMinus method

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, methods, calculator

I'm currently creating a calculator where I'm reading the code from a `String` and adding the operands and operators into an `ArrayList`. For some reason the system isn't carrying out the operations in my `addMinus` method. It seems to be that the if-then statements aren't being executed. I'm not understanding why this is. Please assist.

```java
    int counter = 0; //placeholder for the operators
    //this searches to see if there is an operator
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char c = input.charAt(i);
        if (c == '+' || c == '-') {
            operator[counter] = Character.toString(c);
            counter++;
        }
    }
    addMinus(delimiter, operator, counter);
    return null;
}


//Multiplies the numbers
public static String[] multDiv(String[] equation) {
    for (int y = 0; y < equation.length; y++) {//iterates through elements in delimiter
        for (int i = 0; i < equation[y].length(); i++) {//iterates through chars in element string
            if (equation[y].charAt(i) == '*') {
                String[] nums = equation[y].split("\\*");
                equation[y] = String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(nums[0]) * Double.parseDouble(nums[1]));
            } else if (equation[y].charAt(i) == '/') {
                String[] nums = equation[y].split("/");
                equation[y] = String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(nums[0]) / Double.parseDouble(nums[1]));
            }
        }
    }
    return equation;
}


/////*****SEARCHES FOR ADDS OR SUBTRACTS THE NUMBERS *****////
public static String[] addMinus(String[] numbers, String[] symbols, int counter) {
    String[] equation = arrayMaker(numbers, symbols, counter);
    Double answ = Double.parseDouble(numbers[0]);
    int x = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++) {
        if (symbols[i] == "- ") {
            answ = -Double.parseDouble(equation[x + 1]);
            System.out.println(" " + answ);
        } else if (symbols[i] == "+ ") {
            System.out.println(symbols[0]);
            answ = +Double.parseDouble(numbers[x + 1]);
            System.out.println(" " + answ);
        }
        x = +2;
    }
    System.out.println(answ);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Post the complete code somewhere like https://repl.it/languages/java10 too. And save it and post back a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to this line of code:

```java
if (symbols[i] == "- ")
```

You are comparing references here, not values. You need to use `equals()` method. Same case with else if. And what with extra space between quotes?